# Thunderbird cannot decrypt messages even though it has the private key and *could* decrypt the same messages just a few days ago

Tags: encryption, thunderbird

I can't understand this. Using Thunderbird 102.15.1 on Windows 10, and the private key was added to its native OpenPGP key manager more than 1 year ago. I have old emails that were encrypted, and Thunderbird was decrypting and showing them to me just fine.

Today all of a sudden, all those emails show up with a red message *"The secret key that is required to view this message is not available"* ... I then open the account settings, and I see that Thunderbird says "Thunderbird doesn't have a personal OpenPGP key for me@example.com" ... Huh? I know that's false, because I haven't changed a thing, and looking at its OpenPGP Key Manager I can see the key there just fine, like it always was.

The key has not expired (in fact it doesn't have an expiry date) and it was created less than 1.5 years ago.

Tried restarting Thunderbird, also deleted the key and re-added it, etc. Nothing worked.

It gets even more weird:

Two weeks ago I copied the Thunderbird profile folder from Windows 10 to my MacOS machine. At that time, both of them were able to decrypt those emails just fine. I looked at my MacOS and Thunderbird there still decrypts those emails just fine! In the account settings, Thunderbird on MacOS says "Thunderbird found 1 personal OpenPGP key associated witrh me@example.com" ... like the one on Windows used to say, but no longer does. The OpenPGP Key Manager from Thunderbird in MacOS looks exactly like the one on Windows.

I'm stumped. I don't even know where to start looking ... any clues? What in the world could have changed on my Windows to affect this? I know that Thunderbird no longer relies on any external dependencies for PGP encryption since they incorporated OpenPGP natively. Somehow it stopped recognizing its own OpenPGP Key database it seems.

Comment: +1 for troubleshooting on Mac before asking here.

Comment: The encryption algorithm of the key may not be accepted any more after a silent update of the underlying GPG. Just a shot in the dark though. Please check the versions of both Thunderbird and GPG on both machines.

Comment: @not2savvy but I disabled automatic updates for Thunderbird so I know it didn't update. Also, afaik, Thunderbird no longer relies on any external service/library/executable for PGP since they implemented it natively. If you know otherwise and can advise then I'm all ears!

Comment: You’re right, they‘re now using the rnpgp library. However, the two OS Thunderbirds might be using different versions of it. Perhaps a Windows update changed a library beneath. It’s really just wild guessing.

Comment: @not2savvy Again, my understanding is that all OpenPGP implementation is bundled in TB, and it's not relying on any external (i.e. OS) libraries -- are you saying that's incorrect and if yes, care to point me to any documentation/discussion? Regardless, it DOES list the key in the OpenPGP Key Manager, so it clearly can process it (doesn't seem that it's OpenPGP functionality is broken), but claims there is none for the account email. Moreover, automatic updates for both TB and Win10 were disabled a long time ago -- none received updates in the timeframe that this change occurred. I'm stumped!

Comment: What I'm saying (or rather: guessing) is, that while the PGP library might be bundled, some other external library might be used by it, which has been updated, and which may influence its functionality. I'm not saying that's the probable root problem. I'm making guesses since the information you provide does not allow for more than guessing. Besides that, the best you can probably do is to gather information. You might want to check if Thunderbird has a more detailed log file and/or how to increase the log level there.

Comment: That would contradict the "bundled" concept, but sure

Comment: This might be related to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1865620 and you might want to push the issue there.